# Indexing in multidimensional numpy arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Suppose I have a numpy array like this,
`l = np.array([[[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]]])`
So,
`l.shape = (2, 1, 3)`
That is, in l[x][y][z], x represents depth, y represents number of rows and z represents number of columns. This same convention is followed in C language.

Now, if I use OpenCV to read an image,

`img = cv2.imread('l.PNG')`
So, 
`img.shape = (798, 679, 3)`
Where 3 is the depth (RGB), 798 is the length (rows) and 679 is the width (columns) of the image.

I don't understand why it's different in both the cases. Please help.

Comment: Expound and describe the question better please

Comment: `l.shape = (2, 1, 3)` - there isn't any inherent spatial orientation to those dimensions,  they can be any way you want to think about them. Sounds like you are influenced by a convention.  OpenCV  decided on a convention of putting the color info along the third dimension - maybe it was easier to think about that way - three 2d planes stacked in front of each other each representing a color.

Comment: With a shape of `(2,1,3)` there isn't really in data in the second dimension, maybe only the information that it is orthogonal to a shape of `(2,3)`

Comment: Get used to indexing with `l[x, y, z]`.  In `numpy` it's easy shuffle (transpose) the dimensions.  So order and interpretation largely depends on what suits your needs and problem domain.

Answer (score 3):

One pair of brackets `[]` gives you vector.

When you have nested brackets inside vector `[ [a],[b],[c] ]` you get 2D array (alias matrix), which can be presented as:

```
[a]  # 2d array with 3 rows
[b]
[c]
```

Images are just 2d array. Number of items inside nested brackets means the number of columns of matrix. The following: `[ [1,2],[3,2],[2,3] ]` means 2d matrix, with 3 rows and 2 cols.

Because you call imread to read image with color, you need one more nested list to represent color components: B,G,R. So you have `[ [ [b,g,r] ], [b,g,r,], [b,g,r] ] ]` this the innermost list contains depth of image.

In the notation `[x][y][z]`:

- x is row
- y is col
- z is depth, color component